# Jquery search not working properly in accordion?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here if search text matches the text of `<a> tag` I want to hide other unmatched items.

Here what is happening is if the searched input does not match any thing then only the accordion disappears otherwise nothing happens.

I want to display only the accordion which matches the searched text and hide unmatched .How can I do it here ?

script

```
jQuery("#query").keyup(function () {
    var filter = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery("#accordion").each(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
            jQuery(this).hide();
        } else {
            jQuery(this).show()
        }
    });
});
```

html

```
<input type="text" id="query" >

   <div class="crollable">
      <div id="accordion">
         <div class="card">   
             <div class="card-header">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false">Text</a>
               </div>
            <div id="collapse1" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
           <div class="card-body">
          <div class="col-3">value</div>
          </div>

         <div class="card">   
             <div class="card-header">
                <a data-toggle="collapse2" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false">Text2</a>
               </div>
            <div id="collapse2" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
           <div class="card-body">
          <div class="col-3">value2</div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `html` structure are missing some tags . Then you can iterate through your `[data-toggle]` element and if match found hide `closest` card from that elements.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
jQuery("#query").keyup(function() {
  var filter = jQuery(this).val().toLowerCase(); //get text
  //loop through `a` tag
  jQuery("#accordion [data-toggle]").each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).text().toLowerCase().trim().indexOf(filter) < 0) {
      jQuery(this).closest(".card").hide(); //hide closest card
    } else {
      jQuery(this).closest(".card").show()
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="query">

<div class="crollable">
  <div id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false">Text</a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="col-3">value</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <a data-toggle="collapse2" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false">Text2</a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="col-3">value2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy. its a little mistake that you did.

```js
jQuery("#query").keyup(function () {
    var filter = jQuery(this).val().toLowerCase();
    // Search function return 0 when it dose not find anything.
    // and the Regexp should be using g instead of i so the problem with casesensetive should be solved.
    jQuery("#accordion .card-body .col-3").each(function () {
        var text = jQuery(this).text().toLowerCase();
        if (text.indexOf(filter) == -1) {
            jQuery(this).hide();
        } else {
            jQuery(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="query" >

   <div class="crollable">
      <div id="accordion">
         <div class="card">   
             <div class="card-header">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false">Text</a>
               </div>
            <div id="collapse1" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
           <div class="card-body">
          <div class="col-3">value</div>
          </div>

         <div class="card">   
             <div class="card-header">
                <a data-toggle="collapse2" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false">Text2</a>
               </div>
            <div id="collapse2" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
           <div class="card-body">
          <div class="col-3">value2</div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: tried this now the searched input matches nothing

Comment: Updated my answer, You are searching in a wrong div. you should filter `col-3` that exist in `accordion`. I also changed `search` to `indexOf`. Try inputing `value2` you will see the change

Comment: "its a little mistake that you did." but you didn't explain in plain English what that mistake was. Code only answers are not as useful.

Comment: If you see my comment on top of yours, you will understand the mistake he did. And also he was using search in the wrong way that's all.